# My program skips the if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm writing a program that would make a power of a matrix.
as you see, I'm trying to ask at the for (int n...) loop if n==0,
but when I'm debugging - I see that the program just skips the condition and doesn't even enter it. I mean it doesn't even "ask" the question if n==0...

What is the problem?

```
void Matrix::pow(int power, Matrix & result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < power-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++)
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < cols; n++)
                {
                    if (n==0)
                    {
                        (&result)->_array[i][j] == 0; //Reset result's array.
                    }
                    (&result)->_array[i][j] += this->_array[i][n] * this->_array[n][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I think that 4 loops within each other is excessive. Perhaps use a procedure

Comment: Why `this->` and also `(&result)->` could be `result.`

Comment: `(&result)->_array[i][j] == 0; //Reset result's array.` -- What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: result is a Matrix that is passed by reference. there is no reason to take its address and do a ->  .

Comment: Why not return the result as a return type instead of taking an argument by reference?

Comment: Btw. if you want to only reset the array value before adding the first item, you don't actually need the `if (n == 0)` test for that - simply move the reset before the `for (int n ...)` loop. You don't need to check for the `n==0` at every iteration.

Comment: It doesnt even check the if... but ill take e.maskovsky's advice. Thx!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a boolean expression, not an assignment.

```
(&result)->_array[i][j] == 0; //Reset result's array.
```